# Decoupling identical backbone models in different collections

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone collection of top comments and all comments on the same page, each in their own respective views.

Some of the top comments appear in the all comments.  Given Backbone maintains these via reference, any updates invoked on one of the comments (models) applies it to both models present in the separate collections.

I understand backbone manages this all via the cid / idAttribute. Is there a common way to remove the reference between the models?

Comment: what exactly do you mean saying "disconnect models from each other"? how are they connected? isn't it that you want to have one instance for the same data, over having many "disconnected" instances?

Comment: It sounds like you want [`Model#clone()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-clone) although this throws away the elegance of Backbone; adding cloned models to the collection takes a bit more work for one thing. Besides, don't you want to keep the top comments and their originals in all the comments synced anyway?

Comment: @Bojangles I am not entirely sure how I can separate  any view based interaction with a model just to that one model (even though it also appears in another collection).  As of now backbone obviously maintains a reference between the two and applies the event to both simultaneously, which is the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here. Are you saying that if, for example, you modify the text of a comment in the `top comments` collection, that comment _should not_ update in the `all comments` collection? In that case, you need two separate models made using `Model#clone()`. Am I still misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Anthony Why do you want your models to be unsynched and display stale data the user?

Comment: @plalx Normally, I'd definitely want to keep these models in sync. My issue is for purely UX reasons.  If I expand 1 of the comments, it will also expand the other, which creates a poor experience for the user as the page height updates awkwardly and so forth.  So this is definitely an unique edge case that I am trying to handle elegantly. (sorry to get into so much detail).

Comment: @Anthony, Perhaps the issue is that you are using the model itself to keep track of view-related properties, like `expanded`? Is it what you're doing? Perhaps you should instanciate a view-model that encapsulate the comment model instead? I never really used backbone yet so I don't know what's the backbone philosophy here, but keeping view-related properties in the model seems wrong to me.

Comment: @plalx you are absolutely right in keeping these areas separated, the issue here is that the event that triggers the expansion is model-based (adding a model to a collection), e.g. adding replies to the comment which is a composite tree view (both a model and collection view).

Comment: @Anthony, I undertand the issue better now, well perhaps instead of simply observing if the model had new comments added you could add an additionnal condition to check if the action was triggered by an action performed on that view as well.